# Using Components.utils.import is a syntax error in Firefox 1.5

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

I would like to use the following code in an extension:

```
try
{
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm");
AddonManager.addAddonListener(NFuninstallObserver);
}
catch(e) {}
```

Unfortunately, JavaScript in Firefox 1.5 considers the third line a
syntax error and doesn't process any of the code.

I can replace the line with

```
eval('Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm");');
```

and everything works fine.  Any other suggestions, besides giving up
my desire to keep the extension working in Firefox 1.5-4.0.*?

Comment: Why Firefox 1.5? That was released in November 29, 2005, and security updates ceased in June 2007. At least the most recent update for Firefox 3.5 was issued last month.

Comment: Catering to the Firefox hipster crowd? "Yeah, I like Firefox -- but I like the *original* Firefox, but before it got so mainstream..." Seriously though, idealmachine makes a good point.

Comment: Yeah I'd check your stats on that extension on AMO. I recently checked mine and only 30 people out of 6000 active daily users still had Firefox 3.

Comment: Relevant: http://blog.mozilla.com/addons/2011/06/07/making-compatible-with-firefox-5-and-6/ mentions import becoming reserved again in Firefox 5, and yet Components.utils.import still works. Apparently in new versions of Firefox, reserved words can be used as properties (`foo.import = ""` is fine) but not as standalone identifiers (`var import = ""` is an error).

Comment: While I think its a bad idea that Firefox decided to have a function "named" import, this is actually consistent with ECMA5. As described in  http://es5.github.com/#A.1,  these are all IdentifierNames which do not exclude ReservedWords:
`a.import`
`a["import"]`
`a = { import: "test" }`.
On the other hand the following is illegal because it's an Identifier, which is an IdentifierName without the Reserved Words. Identifiers are used for FunctionDeclaration and FunctionExpression: 
`function import() {}`.

Comment: Also see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=238324 the issue where they first created this import function.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it, but this might work...

```
Components.utils["import"]("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm");
```

Comment: `import` was a reserved word in earlier versions of JavaScript, but the quoted lookup seems to work. (Strangely MDC says that `import` will become a reserved word again. That's not going to be fun!)